# Ignore bin folders in project GitHub

Tags: git

I have my .gitignore file sitting at the root folder. There are several project folders with bin files in them. Is there a way I can recursively removed them from the cache so they will no longer be tracked?

Thanks in advance!

I have tried `git rm -r --cached bin/` at the root, but it does not like that.
I get the following error "fatal: pathspec 'bin/' did not match any files"

I am trying to avoid having to go into each project folder to remove the bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

`git rm` accepts globbed paths (that is, paths with an asterisk as a wildcard).

To remove `a/bin` and `b/bin` but not `c/d/bin`, run `git rm -r --cached */bin`.

To remove `a/bin`, `b/bin`, and also `c/d/bin`, run `git rm -r --cached **/bin`.

If your needs are more complex, then please elaborate on them, or see the `pathspec` entry at https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary (especially the part about `glob`).